# Python update list elements one at a time until sum(list) is reached

Tags: python

I have a list that starts as all zeros. I would like to add an integer to each element in the list in succession until the sum of the entire list reaches a certain point.

Let's say I want the total list sum to equal 24. It almost makes it seem like it works when I try:

```
myList = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

while sum(myList) < 24:
    myList =  [x+1 for x in myList]
```

This gets me myList = [4,4,4,4,4,4], but breaks if I want the total to be something not evenly divisibly by the number of elements in the list.

I can't figure out how to add one to the first element, then the second, and so on, and start back over at the beginning until the sum is reached.

So, I would want

```
myList = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

while sum(myList) != 22:
    myList =  <method here>
```

to return

```
myList = [4,4,4,4,3,3]
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to keep an index, looping around to the front when you reach the end:

```
i = 0
while sum(myList) != 22:
    myList[i] += 1
    i = (i + 1) % len(myList)
```

The `(i + 1) % len(myList)` expression loops the index around back to `0` when you'd otherwise increment `i` to be out of bounds.

Demo:

```
>>> myList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> i = 0
>>> while sum(myList) != 22:
...     myList[i] += 1
...     i = (i + 1) % len(myList)
...
>>> myList
[4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Do know that there is [could just calculate the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353083/distribute-an-integer-amount-by-a-set-of-slots-as-evenly-as-possible), without incrementing values one at a time, however:

> ```
> def distribute(oranges, plates):
>     base, extra = divmod(oranges, plates)
>     return [base + (i < extra) for i in range(plates)]
> ```

which for your sample, with 6 slots and 22 items, gives:

```
>>> distribute(22, 6)
[4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to loop, you can build the list directly:

```
target = 22
length = 6

quotient, remainder = divmod(target, length)

out = [quotient+1] * remainder + [quotient] * (length-remainder)

print(out, sum(out))
# [4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3] 22
```